# Draw Line Arrowhead Without Rotating in Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, arrows

Most code to drawing arrowheads in html canvas involves rotating the canvas context and drawing the lines.

My use case is to draw them using trigonometry without rotating the canvas. or is that vector algorithm you call it? Help is appreciated.

This is what I have (forgot where I got most of the code). Draws 2 arrowheads on start and end based on the last 2 parameters arrowStart and arrowEnd which are boolean.

```
drawLineArrowhead: function(context, arrowStart, arrowEnd) {

        // Place start end points here.
        var x1 = 0;
        var y1 = 0;
        var x2 = 0;
        var y2 = 0;

        var distanceFromLine = 6;
        var arrowLength = 9;
        var dx = x2 - x1;
        var dy = y2 - y1;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        var length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        context.translate(x1, y1);
        context.rotate(angle);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.lineTo(length, 0);

        if (arrowStart) {
            context.moveTo(arrowLength, -distanceFromLine);
            context.lineTo(0, 0);
            context.lineTo(arrowLength, distanceFromLine);
        }

        if (arrowEnd) {
            context.moveTo(length - arrowLength, -distanceFromLine);
            context.lineTo(length, 0);
            context.lineTo(length - arrowLength, distanceFromLine);
        }

        context.stroke();
        context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below, just a bit of trigonometry.

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

function drawLineArrowhead(p1, p2, startSize, endSize) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
  
  if (startSize > 0) {
    lineAngle = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    delta = Math.PI/6  
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
      ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
      x = p1.x + startSize * Math.cos(lineAngle + delta)
      y = p1.y + startSize * Math.sin(lineAngle + delta)
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      delta *= -1
    }
  }
  if (endSize > 0) {
    lineAngle = Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x);
    delta = Math.PI/6  
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
      ctx.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
      x = p2.x + endSize * Math.cos(lineAngle + delta)
      y = p2.y + endSize * Math.sin(lineAngle + delta)
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      delta *= -1
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

drawLineArrowhead({x:10, y:10}, {x:100, y:20}, 0, 30)
drawLineArrowhead({x:20, y:25}, {x:140, y:120}, 20, 20)
drawLineArrowhead({x:140, y:20}, {x:80, y:50} , 20, 0)

drawLineArrowhead({x:150, y:20}, {x:150, y:90}, 20, 5)
drawLineArrowhead({x:180, y:90}, {x:180, y:20}, 20, 5)

drawLineArrowhead({x:200, y:10}, {x:200, y:140}, 10, 10)
drawLineArrowhead({x:220, y:140}, {x:220, y:10}, 10, 20)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
```

If you run it you should see a few samples.
The `drawLineArrowhead` has 4 parameters `(p1, p2, startSize, endSize)`
the first two are the starting-point and end-point of the line, the last two are arrow size, just to give some control to the final user over how big are those arrows at the end, if we want to remove them we set to 0.

Comment: hi helder. i tried your solution. i am doing some scaling (zoom in and zoom out) involved and this is how it looks like [https://ibb.co/PGjSjr0](https://ibb.co/PGjSjr0) . the longer line is my code, while the shorter one is yours and its angle is not the same. i only added startSize * scale and endSize * scale. thoughts?

Comment: @chitgoks if we go down that rabbit hole this question is going to morph into something else, let's keep to one question one answer... if you have other issues please ask a separate question about that

Comment: hi helder. another thing, how can you make the line arrowhead connect to the line tip so the arrowhead will be pointed?

Comment: Sorry @chitgoks I don't know what you mean by `make the line arrowhead connect to the line tip` can you point to the code what you mean

Comment: [https://ibb.co/BrMXCLC](https://ibb.co/BrMXCLC) the arrow tip is sharp. is that possible? i dont think the context linejoin is the trick here.

Comment: You can play with `ctx.lineCap = "round";` and also the `ctx.lineWidth = 5;` I made some change to my snippet